# Why use iterator_traits in a template function instead of just using another template type argument?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator-traits

Referring, for example, to this snippet from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count):

```
template <class InputIterator, class T>
typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
count(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
{
    typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type ret = 0;
    while (first!=last) {
        if (*first == val)
            ++ret;
        ++first;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The question is why use `iterator_traits` in this context rather than taking in another template argument as shown here:

```
template <class InputIterator, class T, class DiffType>
DiffType count(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
{
    DiffType ret = 0;
    while (first!=last) {
        if (*first == val)
            ++ret;
        ++first;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It's pretty broad, but I'll take a shot: iterator traits, and indeed traits in general (like member types) work well with conventions in place. By using "standard" traits by convention, ones algorithms and data structure play nicely with the rest of the standard template library and enable better meta programming.

Comment: Another template class *can* be defined, but once we've done it once, we don't want to do it again for every single different algorithm

Comment: I may be dense, but could you give an example of what you are thinking of in your last sentence ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking about here. Are you asking why we use traits classes, or why this code specifically uses the `iterator_traits` class as its traits class?

Comment: Please excuse if I sound odd, but I was thinking if I could do something like this: `template<class InputIterator, class T, class anotherT> anotherT count(...){ anotherT ret = 0; .... return ret;}`

Comment: Well, sure, you can pass in the type to be used as the accumulator. But that doesn't solve the problem of how to select the appropriate type, it just moves it into the caller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suggestion you proposed in the comments - having the function take in another template argument - will not work as you intended. Here's the code you've suggested:

```
template <class InputIterator, class T, typename DiffType>
DiffType count(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
{
    DiffType ret = 0;
    while (first!=last) {
        if (*first == val)
            ++ret;
        ++first;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The problem with this code is that this no longer compiles:

```
std::vector<int> v = /* ... */;
auto numElems = count(v.begin(), v.end(), 137); // <--- Error!
```

The issue here is that in order to invoke a function template, every template argument either has to be deducible from the argument types or explicitly specified by the caller. Here, the type `DiffType` can't be deduced from the argument types (the `InputIterator` and `T` types can be inferred from the two arguments, but from the signature alone there's no context), so this call would fail with a compiler error. The use of `std::iterator_traits` here is a general template pattern for extracting information about an iterator from the iterator type itself.

Comment: Well, DiffType could at least be the first template-argument. Still not everything deducible, but a bit better...

Comment: @BoPersson Ooh, good point. I believe the edit I've made fixes this?

Comment: @Deduplicator Wouldn't you still need to explicitly provide the difference type in that case?

Comment: `auto ret{};` is ill-formed. There's no good way to get around using `difference_type` at least once.

Comment: @T.C. D'oh; shouldn't post before caffeine. Removed!

Comment: @templatetypedef Thank you for the answer. Can you please elaborate on "DiffType can't be deduced from argument types"? It is just a return type, right? Why can't we explicitly define it as an Integer, in this case? (as we know the count would be an integer)

Comment: Also, please refer [equal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/), where the return type is explicitly defined to be boolean. How is this different from using an iterator_trait?

Comment: You're correct that the difference type will be *an* integer type - the issue is *which* integer type, which depends on the type of iterator you're using. Iterator traits are a way to recover information like this that depends on the underlying iterator type. Since `equal` always returns a boolean irrespective of the underlying iterator types, it doesn't need to use iterator traits.